# creating a text file and moving it to another directory [i'm stuck]

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system

I am trying to create some code for a project where I ask the user for their details and then ask which president they want to vote for; now I have 5 folders already which are president 0, president 1, president 2, president 3 etc. The thing I am having trouble with is creating a text file and moving it into these folders.
this is some of my code:

```
elif vote_For_President=="4":
      open("President 4 vote"+str(Fn)+".txt", "a")

      with open("President 4 vote"+str(Fn)+".txt", "a") as a:

           a.write(list_Single_Name)

      os.path.join(a, "D:\pythonVoteHolder\President 4")
```

however, there are errors. It says
File "C:\Users\Anonymous\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\temp.py", line 51, in voter os.path.join(a, "D:\pythonVoteHolder\President 4")

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jamie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\temp.py", line 58, in <module>
    voter()
  File "C:\Users\jamie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\temp.py", line 51, in voter
    os.path.join(a, "D:\pythonVoteHolder\President 4")
  File "C:\Users\jamie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ntpath.py", line 76, in join
    path = os.fspath(path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper

Comment: `a` is an open file object and can't be `join`ed with a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
elif vote_For_President=="4":
    filename = "President 4 vote"+str(Fn)+".txt"
    filename = os.path.join("D:\pythonVoteHolder\President 4", filename)
    with open(filename , "a") as f:
        f.write(list_Single_Name)
```

The idea is to first create a string variable containing the whole path and then open it inside the `with open()` statement. You will only be able to write in the file while inside this `with open()` statement. In general, it is advisable to use better names for your variables, it looks like you were mixing up `a`, putting it outside of the `with open()` scope, thus it was undefined outside of it.

Comment: it says i have to wait 4 minutes before i can